# SCSS Background Invalid Property Value

Tags: css, sass

I have the following SCSS file

```
$header-img: image-url('images/image.jpg', false, false);
.bg {
  background: $header-img no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

This SCSS is converted to main.css by webpack and is then linked into a HTML file

```
<!DOCType <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link ref="stylesheet" href="./main.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body class="bg">
  <div id='root' class="container-fluid bg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I view my application in chrome I see the following error

[image]

It says "invalid property value". How can I fix this?

Comment: remove the `,false,false` --> make it only `url('images/image.jpg')`

Comment: removed. but it still says "invalid property value"

Comment: only `url( ... )`

Comment: yes url worked. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your first line from:

```
$header-img: image-url('images/image.jpg', false, false);
```

to just:

```
$header-img: url('images/image.jpg');
```